# How to test that a exception is thrown and caught in junit

Tags: java, junit

I need to test the following code:

```
try{
   while((testBean = csvReader.read(TestBean.class,headers,getCellProcessors()))!=null){
      System.out.println("no excpetion");
      i=5;
   }
}catch(SuperCsvException csvExc){
   System.out.println("superCSV excpetion");
   i=0;
}catch(Exception ex){
   System.out.println("excpetion");
   i=0;
}
```

How to test that whether `SuperCsvException` is thrown and caught.

Comment: You arrange a test where csvReader.read() throws an exception (by mocking it, for example), call your method, and check that this method doesn't throw any exception and sets i to 0. Are you familiar with mocking?

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing ... is the info there insufficient for your situation?  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: above is the code, i have to write junit test for it

Comment: None of the below provided solution worked

Comment: Read my above comment, answer the question it asks you, and ask clarifications about it if necessary.

Comment: Do not provide clarifications in comments. Instead, edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> JUnit 4 supports this
> ```

```
@Test(expected=<YourExpectedException>.class)
public void testExceptionThrown() {
// call the method that throws exception
    }
```

Comment: why is this accepted one, the exception was catched already so junit will not pass this test

Comment: "// call the method that throws exception" implies that OP should stop catching the exception and instead use this paradigm for the code block under testing.

Answer (score 2):

Your testing approach is wrong. You should consider each method or class you are testing as a unit that has a specification, an accessible interface (non `private` methods and fields) and an implementation. You should test that the unit, when manipulated through its accessible interface, conforms to its specification. You should not test that the unit has a particular implementation. You may use your knowledge of the implementation to guide your selection of test cases, to choose cases that are likely to be incorrectly implemented.

So in your case, the fact that an exception can be thrown is an implementation detail. You would be wise to have a test case that will also cause that exception to be thrown. As your code tries to catch the exception, I guess this is because the specification of your method says that the method should not throw any  exceptions if there is a problem with `csvReader`. So you could have a test case that sets up `csvReader` to throw an exception.  JUnit will fail the test if the method does throw the exception.

Note the difference: that test case *does not* test that the exception is thrown and caught (an implementation detail); it tests that the method does not throw or propagate an exception in the situation that a call to `csvReader.read` will throw an exception. The implementation is allowed to satisfy that constraint by catching the exception *or* by refraining from calling `csvReader.read`.

Answer (score 1):

Either the exception is expected or it's not expected. If expected then you need something like this:

```
try {
   doSomething();
   fail("No exception thrown");
}
catch (MyException e) {
   // expected
}
```

Comment: If it's expected, you can also let JUnit check for it.  https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing

Answer (score 1):

The "new" JUnit way of expecting exceptions is the *way of rules*:

```
public class ThisIsTheTestClass {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testingSomeBehaviorThatShouldThrowAnException() throws SuperCsvException {
        exception.expect(SuperCsvException.class);
        // Put your testing effort here (setup, call, assertions, ...).
    }

}
```

Look at some [information about rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules), if interested further.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4 has support for this. You can declare your unit test as:

```
@Test(expected=SuperCsvException.class)
public void _testSuperCsvException() {
    // call to function containing your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience is always like

```
boolean caught = false;
try {
    runCodeToThrowException();
} catch (MyException e) {
    caught = true;
}

assertTrue(caught);
```

The reason I dislike to have JUnit handle it is I couldn't control exactly where and how this exception is thrown. That might not be good if I am trying to catch anything generic in a big trunk of code, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score -1):

If SuperCsvException is subclass of Exception try something like this:

```
    Exception ex=null;
    try {
        while ((testBean = csvReader.read(TestBean.class, headers, getCellProcessors())) != null) {
            System.out.println("no excpetion");
            i = 5;
        }
    } catch (SuperCsvException csvExc) {
        System.out.println("superCSV excpetion");
        i = 0;
        ex=csvExc;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("excpetion");
        i = 0;
    }
    Assert.assertNotNull(ex);
```