# Can't catch any exceptions in spock tests

Tags: groovy, spock

I can't get this to work even for the simplest case.

In my class

```
public static String fail(somestring) {
    throw new RuntimeException()
}
```

This is my test:

```
@Test
public void "Throws exception"() throws Exception {
  given:
    MyClass test = new MyClass()
  when:
    test.fail("sdlkfjlsdkfj")
  then:
  thrown(RuntimeException)
  // also tried this
  //throw new RuntimeException()
}
```

My it just throws an accept and the test fails. It seems like thrown is just ignored.

Comment: I think you are confusing JUnit and Spock.  The annotations you are
using are from JUnit.  The base-class in your other question is from
Jenkins and it uses JUnit.  And just adding `when:` or alike in 
groovy (or even Java AFAIR) is just generating a label and is valid code
-- yet a No-Op if you don't plant to "goto" to it.

So this is basically a duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519736/how-to-test-that-a-exception-is-thrown-and-caught-in-junit
with an extra layer of misdirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My it just throws an accept and the test fails.

I cannot reproduce that.

See the `test-question` branch at https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888/tree/351c1a24fa06216c59b858a43562c56cc1dcceb2.

[app/src/main/groovy/red888/MyClass.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888/blob/351c1a24fa06216c59b858a43562c56cc1dcceb2/app/src/main/groovy/red888/MyClass.groovy)

```java
package red888

class MyClass {

    // unclear why this is static in the question, but
    // left static here for consistency
    public static String fail(somestring) {
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }

}
```

[app/src/test/groovy/red888/MyClassTest.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888/blob/351c1a24fa06216c59b858a43562c56cc1dcceb2/app/src/test/groovy/red888/MyClassTest.groovy)

```java
package red888

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyClassTest extends Specification {
    public void "Throws exception"() throws Exception {
        given:
        MyClass test = new MyClass()
        when:
        test.fail("sdlkfjlsdkfj")
        then:
        thrown(RuntimeException)
    }
}
```

That test passes.

```
~ $ mkdir demo
~ $ cd demo

demo $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/red888.git
Cloning into 'red888'...
(...)

demo $ cd red888
red888 (main)$ git checkout test-question
Branch 'test-question' set up to track remote branch 'test-question' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'test-question'

red888 (test-question)$ cat app/src/test/groovy/red888/MyClassTest.groovy 
(...)
class MyClassTest extends Specification {
    public void "Throws exception"() throws Exception {
(...)

red888 (test-question)$ ./gradlew test
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```